# Correlating in-app purchase transaction receipts to reports

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Is there is a way to correlate receipts from the payment object to information received in either the financial reports, sales reports or bank statements? All indications are that the reports are aggregate reports and not transaction level reports. Since my products are consumable it is important for me to know things at that level. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to get reports on my in-app purchases in the sandbox environment.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? Can you get transaction identifiers (or equivalent) from non-aggregated Apple sales or financial reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in the non-sandbox environment the iTunes ID of the person who is making the purchase is included in the receipts.  It says that in the Docs somewhere...

You use that as a link in the reports.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good thought. Is there an API call to get the iTunes ID?

I still worry that this is a very loose correlation. Also, will the reports give me transaction level information? As I mentioned, this is of concern to me since my products are consumable. 

From what you are saying it seems that I will need to balance transactions by looking at the itunes id/productid/purchase date....assuming I get one line in the report per purchase.

Comment: I am assuming you are checking the receipt with your own server...

In the Json result from Apple there will be a field for the iTunes profile ID - make sure you record this in your database along with everything else.

On the reports you can download to a file from Apple, there will be the same iTunes Profile ID.  You will need to download these weekly and digest them into your database.  From here, you can match them up.

Comment: Aha. OK. I thought I did not need to take that step because my app model is the build-in model, but I guess if I want my server to have transaction information I should verify the receipt and store the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but there is no mention of the itunes account details (or any user identifiable ID for that matter) in the receipt data.

The response returned from Apple when verifying a receipt is detailed here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html
Which says nothing of "user id".

As far as I can tell, without a user login mechanism, the only solution is to store the UDID of the device alongside any transaction details in your DB.

There MUST be a better way of course, but I am still searching for it.

- Apologies for bumping a super old thread, but there is not a lot of info out there on this...

Comment: There is no account information in the receipt that you can rely on. Using the UDID is not recommended because a person can migrate to a new device. I think purchases have to be associated with a person according to the in-app purch policy. An app level userid or GUID would be best.